# Java file executed in command line but not in browser

Tags: java, php, linux, apache, shell

I am new to linux and connecting web pages to the server.

I am working on a project which requires a html page to execute a java file in Linux server and display the output back in a webpage.

1. I have created a javafile which is executing fine in command line and creates a results.txt file.
2. I have created a shell script which successfully executes the javafile in it.
3. A html page where i wrote ajax to trigger a first.php file to execute the above shell script.

Everything is successful when I execute the php file from command line in linux, it displays test print comments in both java and shell script, it creates a file from both java code and shell code.

But when i execute from browser

Issue #1 
- it doesn't create files from shell script but it displays the test print statements

Issue #2
- it doesn't execute java code at all so no file creation nor prints statements.

Could you tell me if i have to enable or change settings if i am executing these shell and java code from browser??

I have set the permissions of *public_html* to **777** for time being.

`Error From browser:Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:    os::commit_memory(0x00007fcf589ac000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Permission denied'  (errno=13) # # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory. # An error report file with more information is saved as: # /tmp/hs_err_pid306.log`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Centos there may be some issues with selinux.

The command to disable selinux is "setenforce 0" from the linux command prompt.

Comment: Another/smarter way is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201705/284602).

Answer (score 0):

It seems memory is the problem... Java is not getting memory which is required,
surprisingly its only 2555904 bytes=2.5MB!!
Please try increasing the memory limit in php.ini

```
memory_limit = 10M
```

atleast

Comment: Currently I see the memory_limit as 128M in php.ini file...  Confused on how it can run without any problem in command line but not in browser.  If anyone has any solution or comments please update here. I am stuck at it from last 2 days. :(  Many Thanks.