# PHP exec Java cmd failed with permission denied

Tags: java, php, memory, exec, permission-denied

I am currently writing some PHP scripts that need to invoke jar. I wrote a test script to test Java -version cmd.

```
echo exec('whoami');
echo '<hr/>';

exec('java -version', $out);
var_dump($out);
```

The page return as below:

```
apache
array(6) { [0]=> string(134) "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007ff705000000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Permission denied' (errno=13)" [1]=> string(1) "#" [2]=> string(76) "# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue." [3]=> string(100) "# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory." [4]=> string(57) "# An error report file with more information is saved as:" [5]=> string(29) "# /tmp/jvm-26720/hs_error.log" }
```

I have test the cmd in the console and it is normal.

```
[root@localhost ~]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

**Update:** Here is the hs_error.log
[image]

Comment: In the console try executing: `sudo --user=apache java -version` to make sure you don't somehow have some sort of memory limit set to the apache user in general.

Comment: Also, what does  /tmp/jvm-26720/hs_error.log have?

Comment: @Mike I have update the question with error.log. what's more, I can't exec "sudo --user=apache java -version" success on the console.

Comment: What happens when you execute it? Do you get the same error?

Comment: @Mike I executed the cmd java -version success on the console.

Comment: No I mean the sudo command

Comment: It shows sudo:invalid option -- '-'. I change your cmd to sudo -u apache java -version and I exectued success in the console but failed in the php: exec('sudo -u apache java -version', $out); return array(0) { }

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291615/php-exec-use-of-memory) any commands executed with `exec()` shouldn't count towards PHP's memory limit, so I'm pretty much out of ideas. Maybe this behavior has changed more recently? Try increasing your PHP's memory limit to see if that makes a difference. If not, I don't know.

Comment: @Mike Ok. I will try to increase memory. Thank you all the same^_^

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. I duplicated it on the RedHat 7 (installed on the Amazon EC2).
Only when selinux was switched to the permissive mode - the issue was fixed.

1. Sudo or login as `root`
2. To check the status: `$ sestatus` or `$ getenforce`.
3. To turn it off:

   - temporary: `$ setenforce 0`.
   - permanently: edit `/etc/selinux/config` file

---

After deeper research, it looks that it is better to enable "apache to use the memory" and not turn off the mode:
`setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1`

More info [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/httpd_selinux).