# SELinux, cgi:error permission denied when trying to execute zxJDBC.connect

Tags: apache, sqlite, selinux, jython-2.7

I am trying to connect to a sqlite db from a jython script by importing zxJDBC. I am using sqlite-jdbc-3.20.1.jar and it is loaded by jython at runtime. I am also calling the jython script from cgi-bin.

The script works just fine when it is run from the terminal, but I get permission denied from the browser. The script fails when the script attempts to connect to the DB on this line: `connection = zxJDBC.connect( JDBC_URL, None, None, JDBC_DRIVER )`

```
[cgi:error] [pid 53697]: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/sqlite-3.20.1-cdbdb7f2-9803-4110-888f-e6696ae53e40-libsqlitejdbc.so: /tmp/sqlite-3.20.1-cdbdb7f2-9803-4110-888f-e6696ae53e40-libsqlitejdbc.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

I tried to move the /tmp file by rerouting the jython/java tmp directory using `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/web/MySITE/misc/tmp` and gave it 777 permission just to test, but got the same error but this time permission denied to the .lck file.

```
[cgi:error] [pid 53695]: /web/MySITE/misc/tmp/sqlite-3.20.1-3509ec54-5576-4e50-9d35-b4ffb15b94a6-libsqlitejdbc.so.lck (Permission denied)
```

I saw this post [PHP exec Java cmd failed with permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285304/php-exec-java-cmd-failed-with-permission-denied) , the SELinux mode is set to enforced. I tried and ran the following commands.

```
setsebool -P httpd_tmp_exec 1
setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1 
setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi 1 0
```

I was still getting permission denied on .lck file from sqlite. I then changed the SELinux mode to permissive and it worked.

The problem is the server is running on Azure Cloud service and our security folks want the SELinux to be enforced otherwise I will have a STIG violation. I am not and expert on SELinux. My question is what needs to be enabled or disabled when SELinux is enforced so the tmp binaries from jar files are executed by httpd? I thought this `httpd_tmp_exec` will do the trick but it didnt. Appreciate any help, suggestions or work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of trial and error I am now able to connect to sqlite.

I updated only the /web/MySITE/misc/tmp directory to have the selinux file context `httpd_tmp_t` and all subdirectories and files under it to be `httpd_sys_script_exec_t`.