# phpjasper fail execute from web page

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I able create report in my local environment. but when deploy to server its failed create pdf from jrxml.

with error message:

```
Type: PHPJasper\Exception\ErrorCommandExecutable
Message: Your report has an error and couldn 't be processed!\ Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console
Filename: /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/src/PHPJasper.php
```

I Follow the error message.

Its the output:

```
./jasperstarter --locale id process "/var/www/html/myapp/archives/reports/jrxml/default/invoices.jrxml" -o "/var/www/html/myapp/archives/reports/output/330200006/103/" -f pdf -t json --data-file /var/www/html/myapp/archives/reports/output/330200006/103/invoices_data.json --json-query data
```

run the output manually in the console. And it create pdf successfully.

Any help why its fail when executed from web page?

the output directory both owner and group was apache, and permissions was 777

environtment:

- OS: centos 7
- PHP: 7.4.2
- PHP Frameworks: Codeigniter 3.11
- geekcom/phpjasper: "^3.3.1"

Comment: It caused by apache has no access to use memory
```setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1```
as its [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201705/3750802)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused by apache has no access to use memory
`setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1`
as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201705/3750802)